# How to search amazon with google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want a google chrome extension that give a word from user and search it on amazon website and show search results on a single HTML page to user.

I try it with JavaScript and DOM and it's my codes:

manifest.json:

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Amazon Search",
  "description": "This extension to sarch from Amazon.com",
  "version": "0.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "amazon.png",
    "default_popup": "form.html"
  },
  "background":
  {
    "scripts": ["search.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "https://amazon.com/"
  ]
}
```

form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form</title>
    <script src="search.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Search : </label><input type="text" id="search" />

        <button id="gotoamazon" >Search Amazon</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

search.js:

```
var searchItem = document.getElementById('search').value;
    console.log(searchItem);

    function amazon(){
        window.open('https://amazon.com','_blank');
        document.getElementById('twotabsearchtextbox').value = searchItem;
        document.getElementById('nav-search-submit-text').click();
        var results = document.getElementById('resultsCol').value;
    };

    document.getElementById('gotoamazon').addEventListener('click', amazon);
```

I have some trouble that how can show search results (results variable) on another page?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't include the same DOM script in different pages because the background page is a different context. Required reading: [extensions architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).
2. Rightclick the extension popup and choose Inspect to open devtools for the popup: you'll see errors in the Console tab: `<script src="search.js"></script>` executes the script synchronously, meaning there's nothing in the body yet so your code will fail to get the element. Either use a DOMContentLoaded event or move the script tag before the closing `</body>` tag.
3. No need for the permission to amazon, since you're not trying to access it directly.
   No need for the background page script.

This task may be solved without a script:

1. No need to open the window manually, just use a form that submits into `_blank` and a search URL of amazon which you can copy from an actual search results page on the site (optionally removing the tracking/auxiliary parameters): https://www.amazon.com/s/?field-keywords=derp
2. Use `<button type="submit">`
3. Use `type="search"` in `input` to provide history autocomplete and `x` button that clears the field.
4. Put `input` inside `label` - thus you can also click on the label to focus the input.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form target="_blank" action="https://www.amazon.com/s/">
        <label>Search :
            <input type="search" name="field-keywords">
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Search Amazon</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This will open a new foreground tab with the amazon search. In case you want a background tab, the script is needed, and it should use [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create)`({url: newUrl, active: false})`